# Linq to XML: prevent NullReferenceExpception

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm given a XML that contains optional elements that sometimes are there and sometimes aren't (..). Now, these optional elements themselves also may contain optional elements:

```
<show>
  ...
    <text>
        <description> desc </description>
    </text>
  ...
</show>
<show>
    <title>I'm a show without text</title>
</show>
<show>
   <text>
       <subtitle>I have a text-node but no description-node in it.</subtitle>
   </text>
</show>
```

I need to get, if existing, the value of the -node. What would be a better way to handle it as I am doing right now:

```
description = show.Element("text") != null ? show.Element("text").Element("description") != null? show.Element("text").Element("description").Value : "" : ""
```

This feels suboptimal.. I need to query many more nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with [XPath extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx) for Linq to Xml:

```
var description = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//show/text/description");
```

And use casting to string to avoid NullReference exception when accessing `Value` property of element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `(string)XElement` conversion instead of `XElement.Value` property:

```
description = (string)show.Element("text").Element("description");
```

It will handle `null`s.